# How to I find multiple logs in the same time interval?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns of importance, customer ID# and timestamp. Whenever a customer orders something, five rows are created with the customer ID # and the timestamp of when it went through.

If there is more than five rows, it means our system hasn't processed the order correctly and there could be a problem, and I was asked to look through the log to find the customer IDs of any people who received more than 5, as well as how many times they received an incorrect amount and the number they received each time (when it was not 5)

I want it to show me, whenever the same customer ID (in column "ID") has more than 5 rows with the same timestamp (column "stamp") it will tell me 1. the person's customer ID  2. how many times this irregularity has happened to that customer ID, and 3. how many rows were in each irregularity (was it 6 or 7... or more? etc.) (if #2 was 3 times, I would like #3 to be an array like { 7, 8, 6 })

I don't know if this is possible... but any help at all will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you most of the way there:

```
SELECT `CustomerID`, `Timestamp`, COUNT(1)
FROM
    OrderItems
GROUP BY
    `CustomerID`, `Timestamp`
HAVING
    COUNT(1) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the IDs and Timestamps with more than 5 rows. I am making the assumption that the timestamps for all 5 (or more rows) are identical.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.TIMESTAMP 
FROM "TABLE" A 
WHERE 
  (SELECT COUNT(B.ID) 
   FROM "TABLE" B 
   WHERE B.ID = A.ID 
     AND B.TIMESTAMP = A.TIMESTAMP) > 5
```